# Targeting a device (not an iOS)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, hardware, distribution

Is this possible? I want to target iOS 4.0 and the iPhone 4 ***device*** in my App Store distribution build. How would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly you want to limit your app for iphone4 device?

Comment: I thought I would have a better chance for approval if I submit only to the newest device. I haven't had a chance to test my app out on older devices. Do you think only the iOS is relevant?

Comment: There is only one sensible approach when publishing on the AppStore: Get older devices and test on them (with different OS versions, too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications can (and should) be limited to specific device capabilities, not to specific models - you can use `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in application info.plist file for that (check the list of available keys [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html) in "iTunes requirements" section.)

So the key to be used will depend to what functions your application require, <strike>it seems you can use `front-facing-camera` as only iphone4 currently has that.</strike>

Comment: The latest iPod Touch has a front facing camera as well.

Comment: +1, but if the App doesn't use the front camera and it limits to it so the OP limits the device to iPhone4 wouldn't that cause a problem with approval?

Comment: I think it could cause problems. So the best would be limit app only to specific device requirements that app really needs

Answer (score 1):

You cannot limit to a certain device but you can limit to devices with certain capabilities. E.g. you could declare that your app requires *telephony* and *front-facing-camera*. That would more or less restrict your app to the iPhone 4G.

Required capabilities are declared in the `Info.plist` file

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible and IMHO not wanted by Apple. I don't think that a target device would have any impact on limitation of device, if it was possible. However if your App relies on a fast device and it's unsuable on a 3g you may have to improve performance.